# How to Share content from my application to different apps

Tags: android

I want to share different content via my application to different apps. Can anyone please help me how to share.
I may contain a title, small description and website URL. I want to share like 
this one.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to read about possible solution [here](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send)

Comment: here is only show how to share text and images but i can't found multiple text share,